# How to identify rows of FILTER() when the result is 0?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, office365, formula

Dear Excel masters please take a look. I have a nested function like this:

```
=ROWS(FILTER(Table,Table[Col.A]="d",0))
```

Here's the table:

```
| Col.A | Col.B | Col.C |
|-------|-------|-------|
|   a   |   1   |   6   |
|   b   |   2   |   7   |
|   a   |   3   |   8   |
|   b   |   4   |   9   |
|   c   |   5   |   0   |
```

The inner function FILTER returns 0 since there's no "d" in Col.A, but ROWS(0) returns 1 not 0. Is there any solution or replacement that can make it return the correct result 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you omit the 0 from the FILTER-Formula, you will receive an error - which you can use to return 0 for the rows count:

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(FILTER(Table,Table[Col.A]="d")),0)
```

Comment: @C.G., just out of curiosity, why not `=COUNTIF(Table[Col.A],"d")`

Comment: @JvdV I have to the FILTER function to filter a very complex table that includes lots of array calculation and sometime results summed form multiple column. Filter is much easier for my circumstance. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted to be really pedantic and avoid Iferror (in case it masked a different error) I would use

```
=LET(filter,FILTER(Table,Table[Col.A]=E3,0),IF(@filter=0,0,ROWS(filter)))
```

[image]

Why is the @ necessary? Because otherwise it would check the filtered data cell by cell and  you would get this:

[image]

where the filtered cells are replaced by rows() except where they contain zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I tried the exactly same wrong formula in your incorrect demo and it didn't work. Glad to know there's a way to fix it with one more "@" symbol!